# How to handle events with dynamically created controls?

Tags: .net, vb.net, event-handling

So we often run into that question, and I didn't see a generic answer to this.

The main question is :
I am programmatically creating a control (like a button) and I want to handle the click event, how can I do that ?

Comment: Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11312239), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16245189) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7375061) among many others

Answer (score 0):

The following is for one button that is placed onto a FlowLayOutPanel so if you were to add many buttons the flow panel assist with this.

```
Dim b As New Button With
    {
        .Name = "Button1",
        .Text = "Press me",
        .Size = New Size(100, 100),
        .Location = New Point(25, 30),
        .Parent = FlowLayoutPanel1,
        .Visible = True
    }

AddHandler b.Click, Sub(s As Object, e As EventArgs)
                        Dim bnt = CType(s, Button)
                        If bmt.Name = "Button1" Then
                            MessageBox.Show(bnt.Text)
                        End If
                    End Sub

FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b)
```

What I have done (and willing to share) is create a class which can create one to many buttons at once but the key is integrating which button was clicked from one click event which comes down to inspecting the name or perhaps value in a tag of the dynamically created button or similar control.

Note there is a downside to how the event was added, if you need to unsubscribe from the event as shown it's more effort then it's worth so what Martin showed would be better in this case if there is a need to subscribe and unsubscribe from the event.