# How to make a method for mouse actions in a class?

Tags: c#

I'm doing a school project and I'm not sure how to make a method for mouse actions in a class.
I want to make it so that I can use MouseDown, MouseMove and MouseUp so that I can move a picture box in my case (because my class creates a picture box) to the position of the mouse. This is something I would like to accomplish using a method that can be added to a class and not built in mouse actions from VisualStudio.

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
isDragging = true;

currentX = e.X;
currentY = e.Y;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
if (isDragging)
{
pictureBox1.Top = pictureBox1.Top + (e.Y - currentY);
pictureBox1.Left = pictureBox1.Left + (e.X - currentX);
}
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
isDragging = false;
}
```

Or is there a way I can make some kind of method in Main that can allow me to move those pictureBoxes created from my classes but that they still retain their functions.

Using Visual Studio Form

Comment: Hi, it's not clear if you're using wpf or winforms but for moving an element inside your program you can use MDI container as parent for picturebox

Comment: [How to handle events with dynamically created controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135465/how-to-handle-events-with-dynamically-created-controls)

Comment: Also, convert from screen to control or back pixels with `.PointToControl()` and `.PointToScreen()`.